# Как объединить 2 анимации в Unity-animator

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

Есть у меня 2 анимации(Ходьба_Ноги и Ходьба_Руки c копьём или с топором и т.д.). Как сделать чтобы анимации вызывались одновременно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему через Blend Tree

Answer (score 1):

В вкладке "animator" -> "layers"(стоит по умолчанию) нажми на кнопку "+" и создай новый слой. Желательно иметь три слоя: базовый(без маски), слой рук(с маской аватара, где задействуются только руки) и маска ног(с маской аватара, где задействуются только ноги)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если у вас моделька не humanoid, то в маске надо открыть "Transform" и там уже выбрать нужные кости. Например, вы хотите чтобы задействовались только руки, то в Transform выбираем только кости рук

Comment: Костей у модели нету и эти слои у меня не работают одновременно

Comment: Если нет костей, то не думаю что можно будет использовать 2 анимации одновременно

Comment: Решил проблему через blend tree (это как анимация но она объединяет анимации в 1)